# Error Code: 1109. Unknown table 'revers' in field list

Tags: mysql-5.5, mysql-workbench, errors

hello everyone this is a program to reverse a string the program works fine when values are given, but can't fetch the details from the table.If the method is wrong then please tell.thanking everyone for the help.

```
    CREATE DATABASE rev;
    USE rev;
    CREATE TABLE revers
    (
       entnum MEDIUMINT
    );
    INSERT INTO revers(entnum)
    VALUES(435678);
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE procedure REV.revofnum1(IN P1 MEDIUMINT)
    wholeblock:BEGIN
          DECLARE y MEDIUMINT default 0;
          SET @d = 0;
          SET @rev = 0;
          SET y = P1;
          WHILE y>0 DO
            SET @d = y MOD 10;
            SELECT  @rev = @rev*10 + @d;
            SET y = y - @d;
            SET y = y/10;
        END WHILE;

       SELECT @rev;
    END // 
    CALL revofnum1(revers.entnum);
```

And this is the error
:
    Error Code: 1109. Unknown table 'revers' in field list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can pass a table.column to a function this way.  I'd define a function:

```
CREATE function revofnum1(P1 MEDIUMINT) returns mediumint
BEGIN
  DECLARE y MEDIUMINT DEFAULT 0;
      SET @d = 0;
      SET @rev = 0;
      SET y = P1;
      WHILE y>0 DO
        SET @d = y MOD 10;
        SET @rev = @rev*10 + @d;
        SET y = y - @d;
        SET y = y/10;
    END WHILE;
   return @rev; 
END
```

and use that function in a select statement:

```
MariaDB [ghp]> select revofnum1(entnum) from revers;
+-------------------+
| revofnum1(entnum) |
+-------------------+
|            876534 |
+-------------------+
```

An alternative would be to use your procedure in another procedure:

```
begin not atomic
 declare done int default false;
 declare X mediumint;
 declare c cursor for select * from revers;
 declare continue handler for not found set done = true;
 open c;
 amehoela: loop
  fetch c into X;
  if done then
    leave amehoela;
  end if;
  call revofnum1(X);
 end loop;
 close c;
end
$$
```

giving:

```
+--------+
| @rev   |
+--------+
| 876534 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

If you ever want to give your processors some time of, you could use the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function revofnum1(P1 MEDIUMINT)
   returns mediumint
 BEGIN
   return convert(reverse(convert(p1,char)),unsigned);
 END
```

or, if you fail to remember the name of that function:

```
select convert(reverse(convert(entnum,char)),unsigned) from revers;
```