# MariaDB why do I get error "Unknown table x in field list" when it does exist (yes, another one!)

Tags: mariadb, update, errors

*Using mariadb 10.4.13-MariaDB but I get the same error in a copy of the database running under 10.3.*

The important part of the schema shows

```
/*Database: mamlocal*/
----------------------

/*Table Information*/
---------------------

Name                                  Engine  Version  Row_format    Rows  Avg_row_length  Data_length  Max_data_length  Index_length  Data_free  Auto_increment  Create_time          Update_time          Check_time  Collation          Checksum  Create_options  Comment                                                        Max_index_length  Temporary  
------------------------------------  ------  -------  ----------  ------  --------------  -----------  ---------------  ------------  ---------  --------------  -------------------  -------------------  ----------  -----------------  --------  --------------  -----------------------------------------------------------  ------------------  -----------
...
member                                InnoDB       10  Dynamic        706             162       114688                0         49152          0            4528  2020-08-17 14:48:55  2021-04-06 10:27:53  (NULL)      utf8_general_ci      (NULL)                                                                                                0  N          
...
```

and the table member is created using...

```
CREATE TABLE member (
  member_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  member_title varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  member_fn_1 varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  member_sn varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,

  ... other fields
 
PRIMARY KEY (member_id)
)
```

These statements each produce the expected results.

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'mamlocal' AND table_name = 'member';
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE  table_name = 'member';
SELECT member_id FROM member
SELECT member_id FROM mamlocal.member
```

but these produce `Error Code: 1109 Unknown table 'member' in field list`

```
UPDATE member SET  member_id = member_id ;
UPDATE mamlocal.member SET  member_id = member_id
```

*(The real update does something useful but I simplified it to try to find out where the error was)*

Can anyone help me to identify why?

I have looked at these other questions but still cannot see what is wrong
[Qn1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52842026/mysql-update-statement-unknown-table-in-field-list)
[Qn2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219969/unknown-table-in-field-list-even-though-table-definitely-exists)
[Qn3](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/202177/error-code-1109-unknown-table-revers-in-field-list)

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42f2c5) is an SQLfiddle showing the same code working correctly in MySQL, as I would expect and I have used similar code in many other places without problems to update table member. Using the same code to update another table works ok.

**More experiments showing that table member is there.**

This code...

```
INSERT INTO member () VALUES  ();
UPDATE member SET  member_id = member_id ;
```

...
gives me the message

```
2 queries executed, 1 success, 1 errors, 0 warnings

Query: insert into member () values ()

1 row(s) affected

Execution Time : 0.002 sec
Transfer Time  : 0.001 sec
Total Time     : 0.004 sec
-----------------------------------------------------------

Query: UPDATE member SET member_id = member_id

Error Code: 1109
Unknown table 'member' in field list

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0.001 sec
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be the answer and might help others with this problem.

I had a test trigger on the table member

```
 CREATE  TRIGGER `test` BEFORE UPDATE ON `member` FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
     DECLARE addr VARCHAR(100);
     DECLARE        joint INT;
        SET @joint := is_joint_member(member.member_id);
        SET @addr = 'jgkjgkjg' ;
     CALL dummy2;   
    END $$
```

where

```
is_joint_member()
```

is a working UDF that I've used for ages and

```
dummy2()
```

is an empty, but working stored procedure just to see if I could call a proc inside a trigger. However the trigger might not be working correctly as if I alter it and comment out

```
SET @joint := is_joint_member(member.member_id);
```

then my UPDATE works OK, as it does if I drop the trigger all together.

In other words the error

```
Error Code: 1109 Unknown table 'member' in field list
```

is misleading as it does not mean that the table doesn't exist, it means that something has gone wrong with a trigger attached to the update event on that table.

Something to watch out for in future!